# Present perfect for a dead writer?

Tags: present-perfect

I saw this sentence in a French magazine and I think there is a mistake :

The most famous British Renaissance poet and playwright William Shakespeare **has written** masterpieces such as Romeo and Juliet, Macbeth and Hamlet. His cultural influence was so important that English is said to be "The language of Shakespeare".

I think it should be" wrote" because Shakespeare is dead and the influence that he had is in the past (past simple is used).

In case there would be no mistake but I don't think so why "has written" ?

Is it because in writing the article the author is reactivating his work. I don't see any other reasons.

The magazine is called 'Geo Ado'. It is a French magazine for adolescents

Comment: It is true that **Shakespeare** sometimes spelled his own name like that, nevertheless, the usual modern spelling has an "e" on the end.  And Juliette is also not spelled in the usual way.  Please check those spelling match the original quote. Please tell us the name of the magazine.

Comment: Name of the magazine?

Comment: I have written it  french mag called' Geo ado'

Comment: If it's written by a French person, that explains the tense error and the French spelling of Juliet. French _would_ use the perfect tense in this context.

Comment: Yes Geo ado is a very serious mag they should verify  their articles before printing. Yes in french we would write .a  écrit passe composé

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be an error by a non-native writer of English. The question can't be answered in the terms that it was asked. Past tense would be the normal tense to use here.

Comment: @JamesK I think the question remains valid. An answer would explain why this type of error is common in Romance languages, and why the past simple is the correct tense to use here.

Comment: On the other hand, there is a small number of hits (ca 56) for ["William Shakespeare **has written**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22William+Shakespeare+has+written%22&sxsrf=ALiCzsZXhDjxktL9Ec9t57M0dQmunsFa7w:1656861966487&ei=DrXBYoiuHY2Mxc8P9u-50AY&start=40&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiI7dDng934AhUNRvEDHfZ3DmoQ8tMDegQIARA8&cshid=1656862056476750&biw=960&bih=473&dpr=1.5)

Comment: Is the article a translation? REMINDER: One of the uses of the Present Perfect is to signal something in the past without being specific. Also, in translations, there is often the mistake from French to English where the passé composé is incorrectly translated as a present perfect. Mari-Lou, there is no pp in French....[in case there is no mistake, not would be]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in English we would use the past tense for a dead writer.  This isn't a "grammar" rule, but just a matter of the meaning of the past tense.  With a dead writer there is an implied "he wrote *when he was alive*" and the implied time means that the past tense is the usual choice.

You do on rare occasions see present perfect used to describe the actions of dead people.  However in this case it seems to be merely an error. The French "passe composé" has a different meaning to the English perfect tense, despite the similarity of its construction.